# LINQ TO XML, How to replace values with new values c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Below is my Sample XML File:-

I just want to replace date values with current date using LINQ to XML in C#.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BasicImport xmlns="http://www.uk.SSp.com/SSR/XTI/Traffic/0010" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uk.nds.com/SSR/XTI/Traffic/0010 0010.xsd" utcOffset="+05:30" frameRate="25">
  <SiEventSchedule deleteStart="2012/01/21 00:00:00" deleteEnd="2012/01/21 23:59:59">
    <siService>Ssp</siService>
    <playoutSource>Ssp</playoutSource>
    <activationSourceId>0</activationSourceId>
    <CaSchedule deleteStart="2012/01/21 00:00:00" deleteEnd="2012/01/21 23:59:59" />
    <SiEvent>
      <displayDateTime>2012/01/21 00:00:00</displayDateTime>
      <activationDateTime>2012/01/21 00:00:00</activationDateTime>
      <displayDuration>00:30:00</displayDuration>
      <siTrafficKey>056049263</siTrafficKey>
      <detailKey>056049263 2012-07-12</detailKey>
     </SiEvent>
   </SiEventSchedule>
</BasicImport>
```

Comment: I would be more inclined to use xpath instead of Linq to XML here.

Answer (score 5):

Which date values? *All* of them? Specific elements? For example, this will replace all `displayDateTime` elements with the current date - in standard XML format, which *isn't* what your source XML contains... if you want a different format, you should use `DateTime.ToString` and replace the contents of the elements with the relevant text.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.uk.ssp.com/SSR/XTI/Traffic/0010";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("ssp.xml");

        var elements = doc.Descendants(ns + "displayDateTime")
                          .ToList();

        var today = DateTime.Today;
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            element.ReplaceAll(today);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you should find all the element names which would contain date/time values, and you should determine exactly what the date/time format you want is. For example: `string text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Thank you very much jon.. every thing is working good now....
But only one query i did not wanted to replace time value .. i only wanted to replace Date value..  :-) Can you please suggest me a way forward..

Comment: @Saman: You'll need to parse the existing value, and add the time of day to `DateTime.Today`.

Comment: Can somebody please let me know how can i change date value with current date on just above posted xml file using c#

Comment: @Saman: Well how far did you go with parsing the existing values? I've given you the format string you need, but I'm not going to spoon-feed you the complete code. Break the problem down into smaller problems: extracting existing values, parsing them, combining them with today's date, reformatting them.

Comment: Thanks john,, yes parsing string become successful..  i implemented most of the code.. thanks a lot for help...   but i am stick in this node with attribute values...

Comment: @Saman: Then post a new question which is *just* about that part. The fact that you're dealing with dates is probably irrelevant at that point.

Comment: sorry i am not being able to post question.. do not why??

Comment: @Saman: Assuming it's the reason I think it is, all the relevant information should be in the message you receive, including links to find out more.

Answer (score 2):

You could do on following manner

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        XElement root = XElement.Load("Data.xml");
        root.Descendants()
           .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "displayDateTime")
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(x => x.ReplaceNodes(GetDate(x)));
    }

    private static DateTime GetDate(XElement element)
    {
         return DateTime.Today.Add(DateTime.Parse(element.Value).TimeOfDay);
    }
```