# LINQ to XML how to update values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ TO XML, How to replace values with new values c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637263/linq-to-xml-how-to-replace-values-with-new-values-c-sharp)

```
<BasicImport xmlns="http://www.uk.nds.com/SSR/XTI/Traffic/0010" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uk.nds.com/SSR/XTI/Traffic/0010 0010.xsd" utcOffset="+05:30" frameRate="25">
  <SiEventSchedule deleteStart="2012/01/21 00:00:00" deleteEnd="2012/01/21 23:59:59">
    <siService>Saman</siService>
    <playoutSource>Saman</playoutSource>
    <activationSourceId>0</activationSourceId>
    <CaSchedule deleteStart="2012/01/21 00:00:00" deleteEnd="2012/01/21 23:59:59" />
    <SiEvent>
      <displayDateTime>2012/01/21 00:00:00</displayDateTime>
      <activationDateTime>2012/01/21 00:00:00</activationDateTime>
      <displayDuration>00:30:00</displayDuration>
      <siTrafficKey> 056049263</siTrafficKey>
      <detailKey>056049263 2012-07-12</detailKey>
     </SiEvent>
   </SiEventSchedule>
<BasicImport>
```

I only want to replace date value of `<displayDateTime>` node.  Please note that i do not want to change time value of this node...
please help in this in C# code

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this yet?  It would be a lot easier to help if you have a sample of code that's trying to do what you want and if you can indicate in what way the code isn't working.

Comment: Why did you post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637263/linq-to-xml-how-to-replace-values-with-new-values-c-sharp) twice?  What is the problem with [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637263/linq-to-xml-how-to-replace-values-with-new-values-c-sharp)? What did you not like?

Comment: It was replacing complete Node value. i want only date value to be updated...

Comment: So you don't want to show any effort and expect a complete code written for you?

Comment: SO people doesn't like much that type of comments but i think this is a correct time: See [this site](http://www.freelancer.com/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the DateTime constructors takes Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second.  So, given the OldDate, you can create a new one with

`new DateTime( newYear, newMonth, newDay, OldHour, OldMinute, OldSecond)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = XElement.Load("LoadFrom");
                var TheNodeToChange = trayNode.Descendants("displayDateTime").First();
                var oldDateTime = DateTime.Parse(TheNodeToChange.Value);
                var newDateTime = oldDateTime;//.DoSomething();
                TheNodeToChange.Value = newDateTime.ToString();
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with the namespace definitions...?

Comment: I know, but the question is closed so I don't see any reason to change this :)

Comment: indeed - Jon Skeet posted a complete answer on the original anyway.

Comment: I know I only saw it later on...

Comment: but I think that he doesn't know how to take the old value and parse it...

Comment: @ Clueless....  Yes you are right...  that is why i was seeking for help...  But i am still stuck in middle..